# Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container jersy

Tags: web-services, tomcat, servlets, asynchronous, jersey

I am doing an example on Asynchronous processing using jersy restful web services and getting the following

**Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container**

I am running on Tomcat 7 server.I kept  servlet-api-3.0  jar file in tomcat/lib file .But still i am getting the error.What might be the reason for the exception.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no i am using 3.0 related descriptor.I solved problem by using <async-supported>true</async-supported> in web.xml

Comment: If `<async-supported>` was necessary, then this must have been an oversight in configuration of a `Filter`. Posting the full error stack trace probably would have helped diagnose this problem.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Yes, you are very right, Tomcat 7 implements Servlet 3. It was my mistake (comment deleted).

Comment: @PSR are you using Maven? Are you including all the dependencies?

Comment: @sherb it is working for me now.But i am getting the empty result when i hit from the browser